# Why does this do while loop not end when it's supposed to?

Tags: php

I'm trying on PHP 7.4

```
<?php
    function test(){
        do{
            $val=(int)readline("Insert a number in the range of 1-5 :");
            print_r(($val>5 || $val!==0)."\n");
        }while ($val>5 || $val!==0);
    }
    test();
```

But it just doesn't work as expected. It just leaves the loop when I insert 0, but not when I insert a number less than or equal to 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition is incorrect for what you're trying to do.

```
while ($val>5 || $val!==0)
```

None of the numbers you want to cause the loop to end are equal to zero, so the `$val!==0` part of the condition will always be true unless `$val` is zero.

If either part of an or expression like `$val>5 || $val!==0` is true, then the entire expression is true.

You need this instead:

```
while ($val > 5 || $val < 1)
```

Comment: But what if i want specifically that loop is abandoned when inserted number zero or numbers greater than 5?

Comment: That would be `while ($val <= 5 && $val >= 1)`. Don't forget about negative numbers, by the way. The `(int)` cast from the input string will still allow them.